# Crystal reports, how to select row in viewer?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

how can I select entire row in crystal report viewer, when report is displayed.
I can only select one cell and in that moment entire column become selected, but I want row to be selected. In previous version of crystal report it can be done by default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not entire column getting selected.....though whole column getting highlighted you have selected only single cell.

That is because that single cell is repeated so many times with different data.

For your issue use CTRL and then select all cells and try to perform required operation and check the result

Comment: Yes I can select more cells with CTRL, but I want to highlight one row, to easily check my data?

Comment: Cell with dark border is the one that you are referring.....I don't think there is any other way.... To the extent I know

Comment: In previous versions of Crystal that was possible...
Thank You